# Unable to send bulk email to particular contact list_ids in SendGrid through Single Sends getting "Json could not be unmarshalled" error

Tags: php, api, sendgrid

I am using SendGrid's new Marketing Campaigns API to send Single Sends (emails to particular contact list). When I try to create a Single Send with the "send_at: now" parameter, I get 400 response and this error message:

```
{"errors":[{"field":"","message":"json could not be unmarshalled"}]}.
```

However, when I create a Single Send without the "send_at: now" parameter, it gets created as a draft because the time is not specified and I get 201 response.

```
$sg = new \SendGrid($_ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY']);
$list_ids = '"' . implode('","', $list_ids) . '"';

$request_body = json_decode('{
    "name": "'.$name.'",
    "send_at": "now",
    "send_to":{"list_ids":["222418c1-4360-47ed-xxxx-xxxxxxxx"]},
    "email_config":{"subject":"hello","html_content":"hi there"}
}');

try {
    $response = $sg->client->marketing()->singlesends()->post($request_body);
    echo "<br>"."<br>"."<br>";
    echo '<pre>';
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
    print $response->body() . "\n";
    echo '</pre>';
    return true;
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ' .  $ex->getMessage();
    return false;
}
```

#### So the problems which I am facing are :

1. When I try to send a Single Send using SendGrid's Marketing campaigns API with the **`send_at : "now"`** parameter, I get an error message that says **`{"errors":[{"field":"","message":"json could not be unmarshalled"}]}`**. I am unsure why this error occurs and how to fix it.
2. If I create a Single Send without using the **`send_at : "now"`** parameter, it creates a Single Send as a draft. However, I need to [`schedule this Single Send email campaign`](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/single-sends/schedule-single-send) time as it was not provided during the creation of the Single Send.
3. When I try to schedule the Single Send, I get an error message that requests me to insert the custom_unsubscribe URL in the JSON **`$request_body`**. I am unsure how to insert this URL, and I am also confused as to why SendGrid cannot insert the unsubscribe link automatically if it is not provided. ( I do not want to use custom_unsubscribe URL default unsubscribe URL would be totally fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attempting to use an older version of [the Schedule Single Send API](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/single-sends/schedule-single-send) or the PHP Helper Library.

The current version of the API only supports the `send_at` parameter in the request body. Also, the method call structure is slightly different to what you're using, as you can see in the example below, copied over (and slightly revised) from the docs.

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
$dotenv->required(['SENDGRID_API_KEY']);

$sg = new \SendGrid($_ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY']);
$request_body = json_decode('{
    "send_at": "3752-01-28T23:21:52.575Z"
}');
$id = "ZGkrHSypTsudrGkmdpJJ";

try {
    $response = $sg
        ->client
        ->marketing()
        ->singlesends()
        ->_($id)
        ->schedule()
        ->put($request_body);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '.  $ex->getMessage();
}
```